# Вставка текста в html-страницу при проксировании через nginx

Tags: nginx

Хочу на проксированной веб-странице почтового сервера вывести надпись-предупреждение об использовании неофициального зеркала, дескать используйте только при реальной необходимости и тп и тд и мои контакты. Проксирую страницу через nginx, всё работает прекрасно и просто. Кто-то мне говорил, что nginx поддерживает нужный мне функционал по изменению содержимого страницы, но в официальной документации подобной функции не нашел. Можете ли подсказать, уважаемые?

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
    location / {
        sub_filter '<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8080/'  '<a href="https://$host/';
        sub_filter '<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/' '<img src="https://$host/';
        sub_filter_once on;
    }
```

http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html

Comment: да, этот пункт, увы, не помог. Страница имеет минимум html-текста, всё подтягивается через js, в том числе весь полезный текст. Через инструменты разработчика увидел фоновое изображение, но даже его замена почему-то не происходит (
sub_filter "://$host/rainloop/v/1.14.0/themes/Default/images/background.jpg" "$scheme://$host/givemeerror";)
. В работе с JS какие-то другие правила, не знаете?

Comment: на js location тоже можно попробовать навесить

Comment: с sub_filter_types

Comment: или заменять `</body>` на `<script src="$some.js"></script></body>`; a в some.js динамически хтмл создавать

Comment: а если просто `</body>` заменять на `<div...>...</div></body>` и у дива что-то типа `style="position: fixed; z-index: 9999"`